# Chrome and Firefox no longer anti-alias Google Font

Tags: html, css, wordpress, antialiasing

Recently I've been trying to develop a WordPress site. Suddenly, however, I reloaded the page and the text became super nasty-like an anti-alias filter was removed. I didn't change any of the CSS on the page, so I knew that wasn't it. I checked another website using the same font (Google Fonts, Open Sans) and it was the same way. Another local installation of a website I'm working on does the same thing. I'm running Chrome, so I checked Firefox. Same thing. Only IE 10 worked (Running windows 7).

Here's an image (Ironically it looks better, image may be anti-aliased).:

[image]

The website is http://www.tedxyouthhillsborough.com. If anything go there and let me know if you experience the same thing.

Thanks,
Matthew

Comment: You may have accidentally zoomed. Try Ctrl+zero

Comment: Looks fine in all browsers to me.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I tried that--didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same problem with Google fonts (specially Google Spreadsheets) using **Firefox**. What it worked for me was the next (obviously only works in Firefox):

1. Open in Firefox the document or URL that is displaying "ugly fonts". Make sure to open a Firefox window on each monitor/screen that you have available. In my case I have the display of my laptop and 2 external monitors.
2. Open the link [Refresh Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings)
3. Click on the button "Refresh Firefox".
4. In the popup window, confirm clicking the button "Refresh Firefox".
5. Your Firefox configuration and addons will be reset to default, don't worry techie guys: All your bookmarks and passwords will be saved.
6. Wait until Firefox closes itself and gets open again.
7. Once The Firefox is refreshed you are good to go, check again the page with ugly fonts and the problem should be gone.

Other option insteas the link showed in the step #2 is go to url [about:support](http://about:support). The button "Refresh button" is on the up right corner.